# No matching function for to call operator ++ overloading

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm trying to overload the increment `operator++` in my class But it tells me
no matching function for call to `person::person(int&)`.

The error occurs at line 22
here is my header file

```
#include <string>
class person
{
private:
    std::string name;
    int age;
public:
    //Setters
    void set_name(std::string name_set);
    void set_age(int age_set);
    //Getters
    std::string get_name();
    int get_age();
    //Constructors & Destructor (Overloaded Constructor)
    person();
    person(std::string ini_name,int ini_age);
    //Operator Overloading
    person operator ++(int)
    {
        age++;
        return person(age);
    }
};
```

here is the cpp file

```
#include "person.h"
//Setters Definition
void person::set_name(std::string name_set){name = name_set;}
void person::set_age(int age_set){age = age_set;}
//Getters Definition
std::string person::get_name(){return name;}
int person::get_age(){return age;}
//Constructors & Destructor (Overloaded Constructor)
person::person(){name = "Null",age = 0;}
person::person(std::string ini_name,int ini_age):
   name(ini_name),age(ini_age)
{}
```

Comment: That's not how the postfix increment operator should be written, check your book. Anyhow, the error clearly states the problem. There's no constructor taking only an int as input. But, like I said, the whole function should be written differently.

Comment: You haven't provided a `person` constructor that takes a single `int` argument. (You have one that takes a `string` and an `int`, and the default constructor, but not the required one.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The postfix increment is supposed to increment `this` and return the value before the increment. You get the error because there is no constructor for `person` taking an `int`. You can fix that by:

```
person operator++(int)
{
    person temp{name,age};
    age++;
    return temp;
}
```

Though better would be to provide a copy constructor and typically postfix increment can be implemented in terms of prefix increment:

```
// prefix
person& operator++() {
    age++;
    return *this;
}

// postfix
person operator++(int) {
    person temp = *this;  // needs copy constructor
    ++*this;
    return temp;
}
```

For more details on operator overloading I refer you to [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)